# Troubleshooting ageing router? Two almost identical trace routes, one fine the other not

Tags: routing

recently i have a problem with *Juniper SSG-140*.

It's timing out on pings and also to requests to websites on its LAN.

Here is an example of one of the erraticisms: identical trace routes to similar IPs, one works exactly as expected the other one fails:

```
ROUTER-> trace 8.8.4.4 
Type escape sequence to escape 

Send ICMP echos to 8.8.4.4, timeout is 2 seconds, maximum hops are 32, 
1 1ms 1ms 2ms xx.xxx.208.3 
2 1ms 1ms 0ms xx.xxx.54.53 
3 2ms 1ms 1ms xx.xxx.55.253 
4 1ms 2ms 1ms xx.xxx.55.221 
5 1ms 1ms 1ms xx.xxx.50.121 
6 1ms 1ms 1ms xx.xxx.51.2 
7 1ms 1ms 1ms xx.xx.211.178 
8 3ms 3ms 3ms 216.239.47.223 
9 2ms 2ms 2ms 209.85.255.143 
10 2ms 2ms 3ms 8.8.4.4 
Trace complete
```

The other:

```
ROUTER-> trace 8.8.8.8 
Type escape sequence to escape 

Send ICMP echos to 8.8.8.8, timeout is 2 seconds, maximum hops are 32, 
1 2ms 18ms 19ms xx.xxx.208.3 
2 * 58ms 2ms xx.xxx.54.53 
3 9ms * * 
4 * 6ms 17ms xx.xxx.55.221 
5 10ms * 18ms xx.xxx.50.121 
6 * * 9ms xx.xxx.51.2 
7 4ms 5ms * 
8 * 8ms 13ms 216.239.47.223 
9 13ms 14ms 13ms 216.239.46.85 
10 5ms 9ms 14ms 8.8.8.8 
Trace complete
```

The hops along the way are identical until hop 9.

I've been working with network engineers on the upstream network and they can't see any problems their end.

Why might the results from the two trace routes be so different, when the routes are so similar? Could it be a sign the router's on its way out?

Comment: Have you bypassed the firewall (plugging a laptop directly to the WAN with a public IP) and try running the same traces?

Comment: This is still a very valid guide to using traceroute correctly: https://www.nanog.org/meetings/nanog45/presentations/Sunday/RAS_traceroute_N45.pdf

Comment: @pooter03 Was hoping to avoid the downtime associated with that, but I'm going to try that in just a moment. Haven't made much other progress

Comment: @cpt_fink Thanks that document is fantastic. Already saved to have a proper read through

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to measure the difference between the two traces, you can ping directly 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and see the time response to know if there is a big difference in the delay. You can use the options (for Wndows) :

```
-n for increasing the number of ping and having a best average
-w for increasing the delay of the response
ping -w 5000 -n 50 8.8.8.8
```

Concerning the difference in the results of yours traces, maybe yours packets (or the packets of response) doesn't take the sames routes during their transits. This may be due to dynamic routing in your network.

Comment: There's a big difference between the two pings - 8.8.8.8 averages 17ms but with 40% loss, 8.8.4.4 averages 2ms with 0% loss. I can't understand why it would be so different and my concern is that it's the firewall causing it

Comment: Have you got the same loss when you ping the IP address just after your firewall ?

Comment: There's three addresses for the next hop after the firewall - .1, .2 and .3. If I ping .1 or .2 there's the same loss. .3 however responds as expected

Comment: @Anthony, check the ports leading to those three devices to see if there are errors, collisions, etc. Things like a duplex mismatch can cause such results.

Comment: Ron, it's all the same port at my end that leads to the three devices. Given that one device works and the other two don't, could it still be the port at my end? When you say ports (plural) it sounds as if the ports at the other end (belonging to the ISP) should also be checked?